# TeXShop equivalent on Windows

Tags: windows, editors

I'm using TeXShop on Mac. I will need to co-operate with a Windows user. What LaTeX distribution or package shall he install to

- be able compile my TeXShop LaTeX files without the need to install LaTeX extensions, and
- have an integrated editor - LaTeX build environment?

Comment: Yes, many thanks, TeXWorks will be the solution! I'll upvote your answers when I reach sufficient reputation.

Comment: Glad I could help. Next time just post the question at TeX.SE. I think you'll find the group there extremely helpful -- I certainly have.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site (stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I'm facing the same problem now. Unfortunately, TeXworks doesn't have a native OS X user interface… I have yet to have found any good cross-platform alternatives though…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeXShop does not run on Windows. So if  you want to use the same editor on both machines you could use TeXworks which runs on both Mac and PC.

I too for the sake of compatibility stuck with TeXworks on both platforms when I started my ventures into LaTeX, but since then have moved to TeXShop on my mac. The initial move was due to the built in spell checker.

A very comprehensive list of editors/IDE's can be found at:

- [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Answer (score 1):

I have switched from windows to mac and now I have experience with both environments. Theoretically LaTeX should be platform free and it you have all packets installed you should be trouble free.

On windows I used to have Miktex distribution with TexnicCenter as software. 
On Mac I have MacTex distribution which is TexLive. Texlive is available for Windows as well therefore I would recommend it in order to have similar distribution on both computers. 
Another software that could be installed on both platforms is TexMaker.

On windows (and Mac also using wine) I would recommend editing on Notepad++. It does miracles with functions as: Find/replace in all open files, find using regulated expressions, highlighted syntax.

Comment: Disagreeing with the "complaint" in the first paragraph:  Many people make LaTeX editors that are in no way supported by the LaTeX team nor related with a TeX distributions, and many of them are not cross-platform, but this is not in any way a fault of LaTeX.  LaTeX have nothing to do with how is edited  even if some distributions include a editor as TeXworks for your convenience (that by the way, **is** cross-platform, and free).  Beside, Notepad ++ also work with wine in Linux (but if there is something in excess for this OS, they are the text editors of any flavor and color).